# Understanding typedef in multiple scenarios

Tags: c++

I have the following piece of code:

```
template <typename iterator>
using range_type = pair<iterator,iterator>;

using wordvec = vector<string>;
using word_range = range_type<decltype(declval<wordvec>().cbegin())>;
```

First line: in this case template is used, so the range_type in the second line can take multiple types

Second line: a pair that can take multiple types

third line: just a type

fourth line: I am having troubles understanding this line. What comes next to range_type is supposed to be the name of the object with the arguments. Can someone clear this up?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try reading the reference page on [`declval`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval)? It explains the role of declval in `making it possible to use member functions in decltype expressions without the need to go through constructors. `. Seems like what you end up with is a pair of `vector<string>::const_iterator`.

Comment: Can u elaborate on the claim "without the need to go through constructors"?

Comment: It's mean it doesn't need to construct an actual instance to get access to the `cbegin` member function. I can't give an authoritative answer (hence comment). [This article](https://arne-mertz.de/2017/01/decltype-declval/) seems to have a lengthy explanation of both `decltype` and `declval`. You can see an implementation [here](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/utility#L58), which probably doesn't help that much, but it shows it's a simple (but unfortunately a bit magical) function.

Comment: I got it. decltype just declares a type at run-time and declval declares an object at run-time. In this case the type declared is the type of the return value which is a string. I didn't know you can declare stuff at run-time.

Comment: @itachi_uchiha You misunderstand something, one can not declare stuff at runtime.

Comment: so how is it declared?

Comment: At compile time. You don't need to run the program to determine which type `word_range` aliases.

Comment: but the compiler has to execute another "precompiled program" to execute the functions declval and decltype right?

Comment: @itachi_uchiha Stuff in `decltype` doesn't get executed ever. `decltype` just finds out the type of an expression

Comment: I think your question is more like "how does declval" work. There is a question with that name on the site I believe. I wont vote this as a dupe as I'm not certain the answer there will help you.